# Why does reindexing a pandas DataFrame give me an empty DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset with information on cities in the United States and I want to give it a two-level index with the state and the city. I've been trying to use the MultiIndex approach in the documentation that goes something like this.

```
lists = [list(df['state'],list(df['city'])]
tuples = list(zip(*lists))
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples)
new_df = pd.DataFrame(df,index=index)
```

The output is a new DataFrame with the correct index but it's full of `np.nan` values. Any idea what's going on?

Comment: You mention `reindex` but you are creating a new df? Perhaps you want [`DataFrame.reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) instead?

Answer (score 1):

When you reindex a DataFrame with a new index, *Pandas* operates roughly
the following way:

- Iterates over the current index.
- Checks whether this index value occurs in the new index.
- From the "old" (existing) rows, leaves only those with index values
  present in the new index.
- There can be reordering of rows, to align with the order of the new
  index.
- If the new index contains values absent in the DataFrame, then
  the coresponding row has only *NaN* values.

Maybe your DataFrame has initially a "standard" index (a sequence
of integers starting from *0*)?
In this case no item of the old index is present in the new
index (actualy MultiIndex), so the resulting DataFrame has
all rows full of *NaN*s.

Maybe you should set the index to the two columns of interest,
i.e. run:

```
df.set_index(['state', 'city'], inplace=True)
```